# Android EventListener not firing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

what im trying to do right now is trying to grab a location object that is already in my firebase database eg: Artic base and store it in the localeobj i created but for some reason when i run the program it keeps saying localeobj is null am i doing my listener correctly?

```
package com.example.spy;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class GameJoin extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private FirebaseUser user;

    private TextView location;
    private TextView role;
    private TextView desc;

    private Button back;

    private Intent extra;
    private Bundle data;

    private String spy;

    private Location localeObj;

    private String game_code;

    private Random rand;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        rand = new Random();

        //Firebase stuff
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference();

        //Views
        role = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_role);
        location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_location);
        desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);

        //Buttons
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        //Attach a listener to the button
        findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);

        //Retrieve data from previous activity
        extra = getIntent();
        data = extra.getBundleExtra("game_data");
        game_code = data.getString("game_code");

        //TODO: Pull location object from Firebase
        myRef.child("lobby").child(game_code).child("location").addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            System.out.println("************************IN CANCELLED*************************************");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                System.out.println("************************OUTSIDE IF*************************************");
                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    localeObj = dataSnapshot.getValue(Location.class);
                    System.out.println("************************IN IF*************************************");
                }
            }
        });

        myRef.child("lobby").child(game_code).child("spy").addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    spy = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                }
            }
        });

        //Display a special UI if the user is a spy
        if (user.getEmail().equals(spy)) {
            role.setText("You are the spy. Don't get caught!");
            location.setText("Mystery Location");
            desc.setText("Welcome to Spy Fall. Keep your identity hidden for the length of the game, or figure out what the location is to win the game.");
        } else {
            role.setText(localeObj.getRole(rand.nextInt(3)));
            location.setText(localeObj.getLocationName());
            desc.setText("Welcome to Spy Fall. Infer who is the spy before time runs out in order to win the game.");
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Stuff happens when buttons are clicked
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.button3) {
            //Clean up old game lobby information
            myRef = database.getReference("lobby");
            myRef.child(game_code).child("players").child(user.getUid()).removeValue(); //Remove all data associated with the current game

            //Return to the main lobby
            Intent main_lobby = new Intent(GameJoin.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(main_lobby);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the tomcat message i get too

```
                                                             --------- beginning of crash
05-09 11:01:42.718 3083-3083/com.example.spy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.example.spy, PID: 3083
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.spy/com.example.spy.GameJoin}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.spy.Location.getRole(java.lang.Integer)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.spy.Location.getRole(java.lang.Integer)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.example.spy.GameJoin.onCreate(GameJoin.java:112)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

https://gyazo.com/2b0c1ee92f365f06b1737c99793c96b3
ive posted how my database structure looks like too

Comment: Please post your database structure.

Comment: what do u mean my database structure?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2b0c1ee92f365f06b1737c99793c96b3 this is what my database looks like

Comment: is that what you wanted @AlexMamo

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the `locationName` please use the following code:

```
myRef.child("lobby").child(game_code).child("location").addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        System.out.println("************************IN CANCELLED*************************************");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println("************************OUTSIDE IF*************************************");
        String locationName = (String) dataSnapshot.child("locationName").getValue();
    }
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: im getting incompatible types required string found object error

Comment: what object is the datasnapshot returning?

Comment: Please, see my edited answer. I have added a cast to `String`.

Comment: thx! would u happen to know how to convert the locationName to a class im trying to use, im trying to use locataionName to be a class Location so that i can use its functions like getRole()

Comment: `locationName` is a field and cannot be converted to a class. You can add your data into an object of a class if you want but having that variable you can do what you want with it.

Comment: how would i add my data into an object of a class?

Comment: You can use something like this: `Location localeObj = new Location();` and than set the location like this: `localeObj.setLocation(locationName);`, assuming you have a public setter method in your POJO named `setLocation()`.

Comment: thx i already created my object localeObj = new Location(locationname, "r1", "r2", "r3","r4", spy); is there a way for me to grab the r1 or r2 from that location object? if i try to do localeObj.getRole() itll return a null for me

Comment: To get the data out of the `Location` object, first of all you need to set the value and than you can get it back from the object. That's why the public setters and getters are needed. Hope you understood.